# matlab symbolic solver: how to include the dot operator in the answer

Tags: matlab

I am solving a the det of a matrix which contains the unknown variable `d`. The variables 
`a b c p q B C` are my known variables, where lower/uppercase corresponds to distances/angles. Below its the code:

```
syms a b c p q B C positive;
d = sym('d','positive');
det_eqn = det([...              %cayley_menger_mat
    0    a^2  p^2  d^2  1;...
    a^2  0    b^2  q^2  1;...
    p^2  b^2  0    c^2  1;...
    d^2  q^2  c^2  0    1;...
    1    1    1    1    0]);
det_ans = solve(det_eqn,d,'Real',true);
```

Upon solving, matlab returns:

```
det_ans =
    ((((a + b + p)*(b + c + q)*(a + b - p)*(a - b + p)*(b - a + p)*(b + c - q)*(b - c + q)*(c - b + q))^(1/2) - b^4 + a^2*b^2 + a^2*c^2 + b^2*c^2 - a^2*q^2 + b^2*p^2 + b^2*q^2 - c^2*p^2 + p^2*q^2)/(2*b^2))^(1/2)
    ((a^2*b^2 - b^4 - ((a + b + p)*(b + c + q)*(a + b - p)*(a - b + p)*(b - a + p)*(b + c - q)*(b - c + q)*(c - b + q))^(1/2) + a^2*c^2 + b^2*c^2 - a^2*q^2 + b^2*p^2 + b^2*q^2 - c^2*p^2 + p^2*q^2)/(2*b^2))^(1/2)
```

My question is: is there an option to have matlab output the dot operator in its answer, so it looks like this?

```
((((a + b + p).*(b + c + q).*(a + b - p).*(a - b + p).*(b - a + p).*(b + c - q).*(b - c + q).*(c - b + q)).^(1/2) - b.^4 + a.^2.*b.^2 + a.^2.*c.^2 + b.^2.*c.^2 - a.^2.*q.^2 + b.^2.*p.^2 + b.^2.*q.^2 - c.^2.*p.^2 + p.^2.*q.^2)./(2.*b.^2)).^(1/2)
```

My initial symbolic expressions are actually numerical column vectors, so my idea is to use `eval` on `det_ans` and have it output the correct column vector (doing all operations element by element). I would appreciate any other answers that accomplish my end goal without using for loops as well.

Comment: @rayryeng I think he means the dot operator for elementwise multiplication.

Comment: @David - Yup.  I removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [`matlabFunction`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html):

```
det_ans_func=matlabFunction(det_ans)
```

should give you a function that will accept vector inputs (as long as they are all the right size etc.). You just have to check the order of inputs.

Comment: Would this achieve element-wise multiplication?  I'm just curious.  I've never used `matlabFunction` before!

Comment: It turns a symbolic expression into an anonymous function that takes vector input and does element-wise operations.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the tip!  I learned something new today.  +1.

Comment: yep same for me nice to know! +1

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, evaluating `det_ans` as is does result in elementwise operations. Just have to select which equation to choose (i.e. `eval(det_ans(1))`).

Comment: I don't see how this answers that question? Given vectors `a`, `b`, `c`, `p` and `q`, how would this evaluate `det_ans`?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but resolves my end goal (element-wise operations). `det_ans` is a symbolic equation. If you define the vectors numerical entries (not as syms anymore), you can use `eval` to evaluate `det_ans` as shown above.

Comment: `eval` is very slow, using `matlabFunction` will be many times faster.